# How to output mysql query to csv changing column value using php function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, export-to-csv, php-7

I am trying to export my table data to csv but I need to change column value  using comparing php array or function.

I am trying while loop but it takes a lot time and memory issue makes.

my query

```
SELECT column,$conversionServiceId[column2],column3
 INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM yourtable WHERE columnx = 'çondition';

$conversionServiceId = [
    'green'=>'1',
    'yellow'=>'2',
    'red'=>'3'
];
```

column 2 value select from `$conversionServiceId` array

I cant understand how to select form array.I have more then 100k row

Comment: If you really must use PHP then read in the resulting CSV file into PHP and process it before sending it back to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix PHP and SQL like that. Either you first download the file with SQL, then open it and modify it with php, or your move the conversion logic to the SQL query itself.

Oviously the second solution is more efficient.

If the conversion list is small, a `CASE` (or a CTE) should do it :

```
SELECT 
    column,
    CASE 
        WHEN column2 = 'green'  THEN 1
        WHEN column2 = 'yellow' THEN 2
        WHEN column2 = 'red'    THEN 3
    END column2
    column3
INTO 
    OUTFILE '/path/to/file/result.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM yourtable 
WHERE columnx = 'çondition';
```

If you are dealing with a large conversion list, you could consider storing it in a database table. Say your conversion table is called `yourconversiontable` and has columns `old` and `new`, then :

```
SELECT 
    t.column,
    c.new
    t.column3
INTO 
    OUTFILE '/path/to/file/result.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM yourtable t
INNER JOIN yourconversiontable c ON t.column2 = c.old
WHERE t.columnx = 'çondition';
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Your array 
$conversionServiceId = [
    'green'=>'column1',
    'yellow'=>'column2',
    'red'=>'column3'
];

$qstring = "
SELECT id," . $conversionServiceId['green'] . "
  INTO OUTFILE 'e:/result.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
  FROM nodejs;";

 // uncomment next line if you want to see query string in browser
 //echo $qstring;

mysqli_query($con, $qstring);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

You can fill in your user and password, db_name, put this file in your root folder and test it from a browser.